# How do I combine two values from the same associative array?

Tags: php

I have an array that I need to get a value from within the same array that is unassigned to a variable:

```
return ['a' => 1, 'b'=> 'a', 'c' => 2];
```

So in this case I need 'b' to return the same value as 'a'. Which would be 1

Thanks for the help.

*edit*

I intend on running a function on b's value so the value of b is slightly different than a

```
return ['a' => 1, 'b'=> myFunction('a'), 'c' => 2];
```

Comment: What you want is not clear. Why not just change the value for `'b'` to the value in `'a'`?

Comment: "within the same undefined array" - please elaborate on "undefined".

Comment: I need the same value as 'a' for 'b', but I intend to run a function on b's value to slightly modify it. Should I state that? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I mean the array name wasn't defined. So not this return $myArray[1,2,3];

Comment: "I mean the array name wasn't defined" - and that (not assigning the array to a variable) is a necessity? And if so, exactly why? Please alaborate on the restricitions.

Comment: I was trying to use a certain bit of pre-programmed functionality and the function I was using was returning an array with unnamed array. I originally tried to do something like this: return $myArray = ['a' => 1, 'b' => $myArray['a'], 'c' => 2]; For some reason that didn't work, (threw no errors), but when I used an unnamed array without b value it did.

Comment: The right-hand side of `=` is evaluated first, so $myArray doesn't exist yet; PHP issues a warning (not an error) and substitutes null. Anyway, if you want to refer to a value multiple times, give it a name: `$x = 1; return ['a' => $x, 'b' => myFunction($x), 'c' => 2];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
    foreach ($array as $key => $agent) {
     $array[$key]['agent_address_1'] = $agent['agent_company_1'] . ', ' .$agent['agent_address_1'];
     unset($array[$key]['agent_company_1']);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not clear.
But i am assuming that you are trying to get the 'b' element of an array to be assigned a value similar to the value of 'a' element of that same array

If that is what you need, this will do it.

```
<?php

$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => null, 'c' => 2);

$a['b'] = myFunction($a, 'a');

function myFunction($a, $b)
{
    return $a[$b];
}

var_dump($a);
```

You can then return the array, or do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
<?php
function resolve(array $arr) {
    foreach($arr as &$v) {
        if ( isset($arr[$v])) {
            $v = $arr[$v];
        }   
    }
    return $arr;
}

function foo() {
    return resolve( ['a' => '5', 'b'=>'a', 'c' => '1'] );
}

var_export( foo() );
```

will do, prints

```
array (
  'a' => '5',
  'b' => '5',
  'c' => '1',
)
```

But keep in mind that `resolve( ['b'=>'a', 'a' => 'c', 'c' => '1'] );` will return

```
array (
  'b' => 'c',
  'a' => '1',
  'c' => '1',
)
```

(you *could* resolve that with `while( isset($arr[$v])) {` instead of `if ( isset($arr[$v]) ) {` ...but there are most likely more elegant/performant ways to do that)